# low depth resolution on google-project-tango

Tags: google-project-tango

1. I see that the resolution of the depth camera is 320*180, however, each depth capture frame produces only 10K to 15 K points. Am I missing a setting?
2. I looked at the transformation matrices keeping the device fixed and with an area_learn update method, with no ADF loaded. I see non-zero offsets on the translation values. I expected 0 offsets.
3. Is there a published motion estimation performance document for Tango that specifies latency and performance of the IMU + ADF? I am looking for detailed test information.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. You are right about the resolution of the depth camera and your results align with mine. Depending of where the depth camera is pointing at, i'll get between 5K and 12K points. Scanning the floor surface would generate more points since it is flat and uniform.
2. I think that you are experiencing drift. This is expected when not using Area Learning (no ADF loaded) There is a known issue of drift occuring because of android 4.4. (source https://plus.google.com/+ChuckKnowledge/posts/dVk4ZgVikgT)
   Loading an ADF should help this but i wouldn't expect it to be perfect.
3. I don't know about this. Sorry!